# python package for c traceback for error in python file

Tags: python, c, cpython

When I want to see the code for how something is implemented in cpython, I need to manually search for it, for example,
when multiplying a set by 2,

```
s = {1, 2, 3, 1}
s * 2
```

gives the error,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'int'
```

to find the implementation of this in cpython, I had to manually search and then found this line,

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28890427c58d30f1041b36859733159475c67496/Objects/setobject.c#L2092

which probably is the reason for there being no multiply for set, as there is no `set_mul`.

but I had to manually search for this.

another example is this one,

```
(1.__add__)
```

which gives the error,

```
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

but to find where is this thing implemented in cpython I again need to manually search.

If I get an error for something like `inspect` module in the cpython repository, then I can use shortcut in my IDE to navigate to the reasoning for that error, because `inspect` module is written in python in the cpython repository, so it is easier for me to navigate/find the reason for an error.
like,

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(len)
```

gives error,

```
TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method
```

which I am able to locate through the traceback in the IDE that is here,

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28890427c58d30f1041b36859733159475c67496/Lib/inspect.py#L919

but for things implemented in c in cpython repository, I need to manually search.

Is there a repository/tool which enables to search for the traceback for a c file error in cpython repository?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

```
s = {1, 2, 3, 1}
s * 2
```

use

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 1]
s * 2
```

`{}` is dict and dict dont have `*` operations. If you use the dict, you should have a key.

Example:

```
s = {"first": 1, "second": 2, "third": 3, "fourth": 1}
```